# How to use getCurrentSession in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Configuration hibernate

```
Properties prop= new Properties();
prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", url);
prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", user);
prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
concreteSessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
        .addPackage("Main.*")
        .addProperties(prop)
        .addAnnotatedClass(DeviceDataSet.class)
        .buildSessionFactory();
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    return concreteSessionFactory;
}
```

I use

```
public long insertNewJournalNote(JournalDataSet journalDataSet) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    MySqlDAO dao = new MySqlDAO(session);
    return dao.insertNewJournalNote(journalDataSet);
 }
```

With `getCurrentSession`, I get:

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured

Comment: please add the whole exception trace also add the code of MySqlDAO class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this line could solve your problem:
`prop.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", thread);`